# How can I count the number of reactions in discord.js?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a vote pool with 2 reactions  :thumbs_up: :thumbs_down:  in my bot but I'm not able to  count the number of people who thumbs_up and thumbs_down and I'm not able to return the value back to the program.
It is showing ReferenceError : reaction not  defined, how to define reaction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your code so people can see where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

To get a count of existing reactions, you first need a valid [`Message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message) object. If you're using a poll command or something of the sort, you'll want to store the initial message you send for access later.

```js
// make sure your function is async
const msg = await message.channel.send('This is a poll or something');
```

You can then use the [`reactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reactions) property to get a collection of [`MessageReactions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction). The collection is mapped by the emoji ID if it is custom, and the emoji itself if it is Unicode (such as and ). Each `MessageReaction` has a `count` property, so you can see who reacted to both.

```js
const reactions = msg.reactions.cache;
reactions.get(''); // number of people who react thumbs-up
reactions.get(''); // number of people who react thumbs-down
```

Comment: how can i count it separately ?

Comment: What do you mean? I showed an example of counting them separately in my answer.

Comment: it is showing a error TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefine

Comment: Did you define `msg` as I did in my example?

Comment: s i did and the value of the pool is not getting updated and i am not able to find where the  no of reactions are stored and im not able to call the value and display it as output

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a [reaction collector](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector). To be able to use `reaction`, you must use it *inside* any of collector's `events`. You can view every event [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ReactionCollector).