# How can i fetch reaction count?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hey just having issues with fetching reaction count i have this

```
const getStats = (message) => {
    return Promise.all([
      message.reactions.resolve(SUGGESTIONS.EMOJI.UP_VOTE).fetch(),
      message.reactions.resolve(SUGGESTIONS.EMOJI.DOWN_VOTE).fetch()
    ]).then(([fetchedReaction, fetchedReaction2]) => {
      const upVotes = fetchedReaction.count - 1;
      const downVotes = fetchedReaction2.count - 1;
  
      return [upVotes, downVotes];
    });
}
```

but im getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'fetch')`

i have tryed using count instead fetch but still getting count as null

Comment: [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64843809/4935162)

Comment: well thats a from that when i try ``console.log(message.reactions.cache)`` its empty also i have all the partials and intetns